# installing npm package with npm link results in TS2307: Cannot find module

Tags: angular, npm

I'm building an angular library (clan-auth) which contains common parts of several Angular projects I'm also building. When I install the library from the private npm Repository I can use it's functionality normally. However when I link the library with `npm link` I get the `Error TS2307: Cannot find module 'clan-auth' or its corresponding type declarations`. This I want to do for simpler development of the library components so that I can see how it looks right inside one of the apps it's supposed to be implemented in.

Looking inside the nodes-modules folder the dependency seems to be installed correctly and changes on the library get reflected in the nodes-modules library correctly

[image: picture of library in nodes-module]

package.json from library:

```
{
    "name": "clan-auth",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "publishConfig": {
        "registry": "https://privatNPMRepo"
    },
    "peerDependencies": {
        "@angular/common": "^13.3.0",
        "@angular/core": "^13.3.0",
        "ngx-cookie-service": "^13.1.2",
        "angularx-qrcode": "^13.0.6"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "tslib": "^2.3.0"
    }
}
```

My File Structure of the Projects:

```
 - ...
   - libraries (Angular Workspace)
     - projects
       - auth (the clan-auth library is inside this folder)
   - project (the other angular Project)
```

To npm link i went to `.../libraries/projects/auth` and executed `npm link` then I went to `.../project` and executed `npm link clan-auth`

Answer (score 0):

have you add the symbolic link in the project's that points to the linked library?

`paths` configuration in `tsconfig.json`:

```
"compilerOptions": {
 ...
    "paths": {
      "clan-auth": [
        "./node_modules/clan-auth"
      ]
    }
  }
```